# how to convert filename.bz2.gz file to filename.gz

Tags: linux, gzip

I have a bunch of files with filename.bz2.gz which I want to convert to filename.gz.

any help ?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Rename? Have you tried anything?

Comment: `mv file.b2.gz file.gz`? Of course that's just a rename. You'll have to ungzip, unbzip, then **RE**-gzip.

Answer (score 2):

Having your filename `*.bz2.gz` I assume the file had been created using the following order of compressions:

```
echo test | bzip2 | gzip -f > file.bz2.gz
```

Meaning it is a gzipped bzip2 file (for whatever reason). If my assumption is correct you can change it's compression to gzip-only, using the following commands:

```
gunzip < file.bz2.gz | bunzip2 | gzip > file.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rename then do this.

```
for i in `ls|awk -F. '{print $1}'`
do
    mv "$i".bz2.gz "$i".gz
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would refine Ajit's solution in this way:

```
for i in *.bz2.gz; do
  i=${i%.bz2.gz}
  mv "$i.bz2.gz" "$i.gz"
done
```

Using a glob rather than command subsitution avoids problems with word-splitting for filenames with whitespace.  It also avoids the extra ls process, which is marginally more efficient, particularly on platforms like Cygwin with slow process forking.  For the same reason, the awk command can be replaced with the `${parameter%[word]}` [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) syntax.  (Quoting style of "$i".gz vs "$i.gz" makes no difference and is just personal preference.)

Comment: Hi bkail, the modified solution is very nice.. :) can you please explain the working of globbing charater here. I know globs but I have never used it this way. Well, the o/p here is straight forward but I want to know the logic of i=${i%.bz2.gz}.

Comment: Only the `*.bz2.gz` part is a glob. The `${i%.bz2.gz}` is parameter expansion syntax. I've updated the answer to be a bit clearer on that point, but let me know if the link doesn't help.